# How I can decrypt raw no-HTTP TLS traffic?

Tags: ssl, wireshark, fiddler

There are so many articles about decrypt HTTPS use fiddler or use wireshark with `SSLLOGFILE`

But I can't find useful posts about decrypt no-http TLS

My Android running an app called fakeAPP, phone use wireless connect to my PC.

So I can get full control to Android and PC.

FakeApp uses raw tcp protocol to communicate with server

I want to decrypt raw no-http TLS traffic

We can use middle-man attack, let Android and PC trust fake certificate, inspired by `how fiddler works`

I try use fiddler, but fiddler designed for HTTPS, so I cannot see any traffic in fiddler panel

Can we implement this feature in wireshark?

My question is:

**How I can decrypt raw no-HTTP traffic?**

I need to debug server web interface, so I perfer use GUI software

Comment: It is unclear for me what your problem really is: Wireshark TLS decryption is not restricted to HTTPS but can handle any  TLS encapsulated protocol as long as it is TLS from start like in HTTPS. Of course you still need to have access to either the private key of the certificate (only when RSA key exchange is used) or to the (pre-)master secret - but this is specific to the application you analyze on how to  get this secret from the application.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry for my bad English. 

Yes, I should use wireshark to decrypt it-

but how I get secret key? I don't have server's private key,

for example, if server is `google.com`, app is `gmail`, should I signed google certificate by myself, let my phone and pc trust me as authority?

it's complex! I don't want to do that manually

Comment: The main point of TLS is that an attacker which has no access to the key or secret cannot decrypt the data. Thus, if you don't have access to these secrets you are considered an enemy of the application and should not have access in the first place. If it is your own application then you can add the necessary functionality to export the secrets. If you can change which certificates the application trusts you might use [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) which is not restricted to HTTPS only for active MITM.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If I use middle-man attack theory, create certificate named as DO_NOT_TRUST_ME, and replace real certificate. I can let my phone trust this fake authority. I have full control to phone and proxy pc. Can I get key from TLS handshake?

Comment: If you would be able to get the key just by sniffing the TLS handshake then TLS would be severely broken - i.e. no you can't. But active man in the middle with a fake certificate does not require you to get the key in the first place - did you even had a closer look at mitmproxy?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I haven't give a try to mitmproxy, I need time :), I think I should re-think how TLS works